# Problems with the scalebar not CRS related in QGIS

Tags: qgis

When I add one layer to the map, open it in the print composer and add a scale bar the scale bar is fine.  I can add layers (with the same CRS) and everything is fine.
Once there are two layers in my map and I open a new print composer and add a scale bar it comes out wrong (just a 0 with a line under it).  This is still the case when using the same two layers that I had in the original print composer.
Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?
Rachel

Comment: It works fine for me in version 1.9 Master.  Can you state which version you are using.  Also, I assume you've tried adjusting the number and size of segments for the second scale bar and ensuring it is associated with the correct map layer?

Comment: also check the scale of the map you are using in composition. the scale bar adjusts automatically.

Comment: Version 1.8.0 Lisboa.  Yeah, I've tried figetting with all the settings it either works fine or not.  If I try and change the settings it does change whats there but it doesn't create any segments no matter what I do.  I've doing the same thing that I did earlier that worked and its not working now.  Should I reinstall?

Comment: Gerald, are you referring to the segment size and the map units per bar unit?  If I change them the 0 changes, but it doesn't get any segments.